# I have 3 recipes differently but all three recipes 90% code is common how can I replace the code with function or with any recipe in 3 recipes

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have 3 recipes differently but all three recipes 90% code is common how can I replace the code with function or with any recipe in 3 recipes

```
 cldbNodes = search(:node, "cldb:true")


 zkNodes = search(:node, "zk:true")





 zks= Array.new
 zkNodes.each do |zk|
    zks.push zk["fqdn"]
end




  cldbs= Array.new
     cldbNodes.each do |cd|
     cldbs.push cd["fqdn"]
  end
```

Comment: Please post the three recipes to a gist or similar

Comment: You can put the common code into a separate recipe and use `include_recipe` directive in the 3 recipes that are similar.

Comment: I have included include_recipe "::searchb"

Comment: I have included include_recipe "::searchb"   but  variables are not passed from parent to child recipe

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options

You could create a library or LWRP.

Or you could just create a single recipe and include it. Depends on what your doing.

The most common pattern that I have seen is to create three recipes files and an attribute that calls out your specific task.